# Having trouble with DateParse and 24hr clock when comparing 2 times

Tags: vb.net, datetime, dateparser

I have a solution where files with differing filenames need to be matched into pairs before processing. Although the files have differing names, as part of the name they both contain a timestamp as part of the filename. Before matching, I need to ensure that the 2nd part of the pair is within 90minutes of the first based on this timestamp. The client process creates 3 pairs a day so I need to ensure I match first run with first run and second run with second and so on.

The code is working fine except for where the second run is after midday and although the timestamp is in HHmm, the value returned from DateParse will not be.

```
 Dim datIDTIme = Date.ParseExact(datID, "HHmm", Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
 Dim runIDTIme = Date.ParseExact(strRunID, "HHmm", Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
 If DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, datIDTIme, runIDTIme) < 90 Then ...
```

So for a file that had 1446 in the filename: I get back this as value #10/26/2023 02:46:00 PM# and the DateDiff would return -361 like it has counted back to 2am. How do I force it to return the time as 24hr?

datID is 1446 (PAG129D-PRFREST~PPCB02~CBF001D~T~PAG129D-1446_231024_1050795000.DAT)
strRunID is 0845 (T.PR.IPW.PSL1311.11082023.0845.PERS.0.1042083000.STEP3.162.194.AFP)

Comment: datID is 1446 (PAG129D-PRFREST~PPCB02~CBF001D~T~PAG129D-1446_231024_1050795000.DAT)
strRunID is 0845 (T.PR.IPW.PSL1311.11082023.0845.PERS.0.1042083000.STEP3.162.194.AFP)

Comment: Are you saying that you want a string result like "6:01"? Or are you saying that if the result is negative then you want to add 1440 minutes? (1440 = 24 * 60)

Comment: I need to work out the time difference between the 2 values so for a matching pair I would see something like datID = 0746 and strID = 0845 so datediff returns 59 but when I have datID = 1446 I get -361 like it has taken the DateParse value of 02:00 PM but ignored the PM and treated it as 0246 AM instead of 1446

Comment: With times of 08:45 and 14:46 - there is a 361 minute difference. Whether you get a +361 or -361 will depend on which way round the two parameters are passed to `DateDiff`. You may want to be using `Math.Abs` to remove the '-' from a negative result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write

```
Dim delta = (runIDTIme - datIDTIme).Duration
```

then `delta` will be a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan) with the absolute value of the difference. You can use things like `delta.TotalMinutes` to get the value of the timespan in minutes, or (as pointed out by user jmcilhinney in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77365469/having-trouble-with-dateparse-and-24hr-clock-when-comparing-2-times/77365850?noredirect=1#comment136394330_77365850)) for the example in the question you might use something like:

```
If delta <= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90) Then
```

which makes it easy to see that you mean 90 minutes.

Comment: To address the specific problem mentioned in the question, you'd use something like `If delta <= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90) Then`.